# php mysql drop down list

Tags: php, mysql, drop-down-menu

I have a PHP form that shows data from a MySQL table. Each row obviously has different data, what I want to do is have a drop down list that displays data relevant to the data entry in each row.

for example, lets say I have two tables. Fruit and Fruit_Colors, as below:

[image]
[image]

so if my PHP Form was displayed as below, the MySQL data named fruits would display the data in the Fruit column. The color would then be fetched from the Fruit_Colors table depending on the PHP form output value in field 'Fruit'. so the drop down list for each row will be different.

[image]

my PHP form table syntax is:

```
<table id="hor-minimalist-a">
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Fruit</th>
        <th>Color</th>
        </tr>
<? while($row = $fruits->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) { ?>
    <tr>
        <td><? echo $row['id']; ?></td>
        <td><? echo $row['fruit']; ?></td>
        <td><SELECT NAME="fruitcolor" id="fruitcolor">
            <OPTION VALUE=0 >
             *// what goes here???*
            </option>
            </SELECT> 
        </td>
    </tr>
<? } ?>
</table>
```

Any advice how I can complete this would be appreciated. remember this table could be up to 50 rows so need a dynamic way of passing the 'fruit' value to the drop down list.

Syntax I know for the drop down list populations is:

```
    function fruitcolor_dropdown($db)  
  {    
    $result = $db->query("select color from Fruit_Color where Fruit=*'outputted value'*"); 
    return $result; 
  } 
  $colors= fruitcolor_dropdown($db); 
  while($row = $colors->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
  $color=$row["color"];
  $optionsfruitcolors.="<OPTION VALUE=\"$color\">".$color; 
  }
```

Advice appreciated as always. Thanks and Regards.

Comment: place the while loop in the select, echo the values there.

Comment: Good DB design would have the `fruit_color` table using `fruitID` instead of `fruit_name` as the linking field. You should also have a unique ID field on this table, otherwise it would be impossible to delete a record or correct a spelling (eg you have `Yello` bananas in the table, but how would you fix that without a reference ID?)

Comment: @AmazingDreams, thanks for your time. any code snippet example?

Comment: Thanks @SDC, example given is just a simplified example of what I want to achieve, not my actual database by any means. appreciate the input though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be bad idea to connect and fire query two time when you can do it in single query-
you can see [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d2c73/2)

```
$query = "select f.*,group_concat(color SEPARATOR '|') as fcolor from fruit F Left join fruit_color fc using (fruit) group by fc.fruit";
```

Above will be your query and you will loop it like below:

```
<? while($row = $fruits->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) { ?>
    <tr>
        <td><? echo $row['id']; ?></td>
        <td><? echo $row['fruit']; ?></td>
        <td><SELECT NAME="fruitcolor" id="fruitcolor">
            <OPTION VALUE=0 >
             <?php 
               $array = explode("|", $fcolor);
               $count = count($array);
               for($loop=0;$loop<$count;$loop) {
                 echo "<option>".$array[$loop]."</option>";
               }                                       
              ?>
            </option>
            </SELECT> 
        </td>
    </tr>
<? } ?>
```

Comment: Hi @Suresh, thanks for your time. any chance you can elaborate on what is happening here, way over my head. Thanks again.

Comment: @Smudger: if you run query you will get data fruitname (Apple), color(red|green) in a signle row because of group_concat. And in your while loop you can create your dropdown by just exploding it by "|"(pipe). So no need to fire query two times.

Comment: @Smudger: please have a look at the demo link.

Comment: Thanks Suresh, Awesome logic, thank you. will give it a go now and can use this in a whole bunch of other instances. Thank you

Comment: Hi @Suresh, trying to apply the PHP portion of the logic but this is causing my browser to 'hang'.  the MySQL query result field 'fruit' has the array with the |  separator. in the php I have the same syntax as you just with `$fcolor` being replaced by `$row['fruit']; ` Any ideas why this would hang? Am I missing something, thanks again for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Check this out. We create a function to generate the dropdown options. It accepts the DB and the fruit as parameters --> loops through and makes the DOM --> outputs it to the browser.

**PHP Function**

```
function getColors($db, $fruit)
{
    $result = $db->query(
            sprintf("select color from Fruit_Color where Fruit = '%s'",
                    $fruit
            )
    );

    $output = '';
    while($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
        $output .= sprintf(
                '<option value="%s">%s</option>', 
                $row['color'], 
                $row['color']
        );
    }

    return $output;
}
```

**Template**

```
<? while($row = $fruits->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) { ?>
    <tr>
        <td><? echo $row['id']; ?></td>
        <td><? echo $row['fruit']; ?></td>
        <td><SELECT NAME="fruitcolor" id="fruitcolor">
             <?php echo getColors($db, $row['fruit']); ?>
            </SELECT> 
        </td>
    </tr>
<? } ?>
```

Comment: Hi @phpisuber01, thanks for the reply. works 100%. thank you. question, how efficient is this method as it is completing one MySQL query per row. 500 rows = 500 queries? is this best practice? Thanks again

Comment: @Smudger It's not the most efficient thing ever, no. Unless you get insane with it you shouldnt have an issue. The best practice would be a different method to store the colors and/or a SQL JOIN to access the colors and the fruit in a single query and handle it from there. I am not as good with SQL as I'd like to be, so I cannot provide much direction there. If you look at Suresh's answer below he has an example of a SQL query to access both in one shot.

Answer (score 0):

use this in selectbox

```
function fruitcolor_dropdown($db)  
{    
   $result = $db->query("select color from Fruit_Color where Fruit=*'outputted value'*"); 
   return $result;
   while($row = $colors->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
      $color=$row["color"];
      $optionsfruitcolors.="<OPTION VALUE=\"$color\">".$color; 
   }  
} 
<select name="fruitcolor" id="fruitcolor">
   <?php  $colors= fruitcolor_dropdown($db); ?> 
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks, How do I pass the fruit to the MySQL statement to replace 'outputted value' in question?